# Redux Toolkit Query status deprecated

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I was using the `status` flag in the `redux-toolkit/query` to indicate if the state is `pending` or `fulfilled` or `rejected`, but `status` is now deprecated. How can I use the combination of `isLoading`, `isFetching`, `isSuccess` to get the query state?

I think when `isLoading` and `isFetching` are false and `isSuccess` is true, then it is fullfilled?

```js
const {
  data,
  isLoading,
  isError,
  isFetching,
  isSuccess,
  status
} = useGetUsersQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your const is fine so far. I would solve solve this by simply using if-statements in that case. So maybe you could use some handling like this to take action:

```
if (isLoading || isFetching) { ... }
else if (isSuccess) { ... }
else if (isError) { ... }
```

For this you can proceed on your prefered action you want to do based on your state.

Comment: And in which case the state is `rejected`?

Comment: In the last statement, when isError is true your query had an issue and therefore your query is rejected.